# Unable to model data as a tree in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a tree with the following models and schema respectively

a)

```
class RecruitmentPhase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cohort, optional: true
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Cohort', required: false , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :disease_phaseid_questionnaires, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :phase_id
  def phase_name_ret
    phase_name
  end
end
```

```
  create_table "recruitment_phases", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "phase_id"
    t.string "phase_token"
    t.string "phase_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "parent_id"
  end
```

b)

```
class Cohort < ApplicationRecord
end
```

```
  create_table "cohorts", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "disease_code_id"
    t.string "disease_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "patient_id"
    t.integer "recruitment_phase_ids"
    t.index ["patient_id"], name: "index_cohorts_on_patient_id"
  end
```

c)

```
class Source < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recruitment_phase, class_name: 'recruitment_phase', foreign_key: 'recruitment_phase_id'
end
```

```
  create_table "sources", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "source_id"
    t.string "source_token"
    t.string "source_name"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I would like to model the data as follows using closure tree but failed to do so as they are multiple models with different data members. Can anyone let me know how I can approach this problem?

```
Cohort
  |_____RecruitmentPhase
           |_______________Source
```

Answer (score 1):

Migrations

```
rails generate model Cohort
rails generate model RecruitmentPhase cohort:references
rails generate model Source recruitment_phase:references
```

Models

```
# app/models/cohort.rb
has_many :recruitment_phases
has_many :sources, through: :recruitment_phases

# app/models/recruitment_phase.rb
belongs_to :cohort
has_many :sources

# app/models/sources.rb
belongs_to :recruitment_phase
has_one :cohort, through: :recruitment_phase
```

Comment: This answer doesn't follow Ruby on Rails naming conventions which are likely to lead to problems later on. Would you mind fixing your answer and using underscore association names?

Comment: I am new in ROR so can you help me to improve above code